# How to connect three-line code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, line

I'm creating an application using Visual Studio 2010 C#.

I have a string in-line in my code which causes the code to not compile.  The string contains line breaks and so spans over multiple lines, rather than being on a single line.

What should I do so that I can keep the string with the line breaks but also make my code compile?

Comment: I don't understand your question. And how is this related to winforms?

Comment: A little code is worth a thousand words! AFAIK, modern languages like C# just allow to break lines anywhere a space can be put, so you shouldn't have to do anything special for splitting lines in several parts.

Comment: Are you talking about a string constant which spans over three lines? I.e. an expression enclosed in quotes (`"..."`)? In that case add the `@` sign in front of first quote: `@"you can span multiple lines now"`.

Comment: as others have said post a snippet of code and we will edit the question to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: Please be more concise in your question, thanks. Possibly even adding example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use the `@` sign before your string to allow it to be treated as a string literal and span multiple lines.

```
string myString = @"blah blah
                     blah blah
                     blah blah";
```

if your string contains the `"` character they need to be doubled as I don't think that escaping will work in a string literal:

```
string myString = @"blah ""blah""
                     blah blah
                     ""blah"" blah";
```

read more about string literals in the spec [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: gosh. How did you extract that from the original question? :) +1

Comment: I am very impressed that you could understand the problem sean has from this question which many people find it hard to understand .

Comment: Well, the question did state *I do have a series of characters which made my codes to have an error*. :)

Comment: never, never ever would I have been able to decipher this!

Comment: @Sam Holder: Thank you for helping. Again, I'm so sorry for the very-difficult-to-understand question. Thank you!

Comment: @sean, I edited your question to try and make it clearer.  please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply concatenate strings. So

```
string s = "I am a very long string that will probably not adhere to your coding " +
    "guidelines. So I am split across several concateneted strings.";
s += "Since this might look silly the += operator is used, too.";
```

will put all there lines into the string s.

Does this answer your questions?